# How does this part of a BASH script work?

Tags: bash, scripting

Please could somebody explain how lines 3 and 8 work in this portion from a BASH script that I'm a bit confused with? It's to work out which USB drive to use for a backup. Many thanks.

```
1 WEEK_NO=`date +%U | sed -e 's/^0\+//g'`
2
3 (( USB_NN_IDX = $WEEK_NO % 2 ))
4
5 USB_DRIVES[0]="usb03"
6 USB_DRIVES[1]="usb04"
7
8 USB_NN=${USB_DRIVES[$USB_NN_IDX]}
```

Comment: Many thanks all. You've made me understand it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On line 3 double parentheses are used in order to make sure that the expression between them is evaluated as arithmetic expression. `$WEEK_NO % 2` returns the remainder of the division of *$WEEK_NO* by 2, so the result is always **0** or **1**, depending on the *$WEEK_NO* (if it's **even**, result is **0**; if it's **odd**, result is **1**).

USB_DRIVES is an indexed array, and depending on the result of the evaluation on line 3, on line 8 one of its values is retrieved.

You can look at `man 1 bash` for more information. The relevant information is in the *ARITHMETIC EVALUATION* and *Arrays* sections.

Answer (score 1):

```
(( USB_NN_IDX = $WEEK_NO % 2 ))
```

This one is used for calculation. It will let `USB_NN_IDX` equal to the remainder of an integer division operation variable `WEEK_NO` to 2.

```
USB_NN=${USB_DRIVES[$USB_NN_IDX]}
```

this one will let `USB_NN` variable equal to one of `USB_DRIVES[0]` or `USB_DRIVES[1]` depending on `USB_NN_INX` value.
You can use any implementation in bash to equal one variable to another from following:

```
A=$B
A=${B}
```

both are allowed and last one is used here. Also in array you can use index as variable two.

Answer (score 1):

The (( )) notation is a shorthand for `let`, read more [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internal.html). So:

(( USB_NN_IDX = $WEEK_NO % 2 ))

Sets `USB_NN_IDX` to [modulo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) 2 of week number, i.e. 0 or 1. This number is used as an index into the `USB_NN` array.

Answer (score 1):

Line 3 ((...)) - is just an integer math embedded into shell. "%" - is a MODULO/REMINDER operator, complementary to the "/" that return integer part of division. In your case line 3 return 0 or 1 depends on week-number. Then that number substituted into device name USBx - USB_0 or USB_1.

Seems like backups written on a different flash-drives depends on even/odd week-number.